# Connect SQL Server Reporting Services to SQL Anywhere database (ASA/ASE)

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, sap-ase, sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

Is there any way to connect SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services to a Sybase SQL Anywhere database (ASA or ASE)? Maybe using ODBC...

If so, have you done it? Kindly share experiences and any notable considerations.

Answer (score 1):

Our environment is x64 SQL RS but needs to connect x86 SQL Anywhere 9.0. 64bit SQL doesn't recognize 32bit ODBC SQL Anywhere. We resolved the issue by installing a x86 SQL Server 2008 R2 express, setup a System ODBC for SQL anywhere and linked server to SQL Anywhere on SQL instance.

1. Check "Allow inprocess" in the the linked servers->Provider->ASAProv.90. Restart SQL Service
2. Linked server -> Server Options: Set RPC and RPC Out both to True.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success setting up the Data Source Type (DPE) as OLEDB  and using the ASA 9.0 OLEDB provider.  The connection string editor in VS2008 does not allow me to create a connection string that works, so  I just type in the entire connection string as follows:

```
Provider=ASAProv;Eng=[ASAInstanceName];Dbn=[ASADatabase];Uid=[ASAUser];Pwd=[ASAPwd];Links=tcpip(host=[servername])
```

Replace the the portions with square brackets with the values that are appropriate for your installation. The square brackets should NOT be in your final connection string and quotes are not need either.  The links statement at the end is probabaly not necessary if the database is on your local machine.  Even though I included the database username and password, it didn't seem to be used.  I also had to set them in the DataSource Credentials.  When deployed to SSRS, I also set them in the DataSource to be saved on the server.

I've noticed that performance is VERY slow when previewing the report in local mode in VS 2008.  Instead, I have started deploying my report everytime I want to "preview" it so I can look at it on the SSRS server through a browser.  Performance is much better that way.

I am looking for a BETTER solution than what I've described as I've quickly found that multiple-value parameters are not supported with this type of connection to ASA.  If you find a better solution, perhaps using the ASA ADO.NET Provider, please post.  From what I've found though, there is no DPE that exists for ASA.